# Linked lists: Unable to access a vector of structs within another struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, linked-list

I have a linked list, with nodes built up from the following structure:

```
struct node{
    Instr anInstr;
    node *next;
    std::vector<dependency *> instrDep;
};
```

The vector is a set of extra links that connect the element to a set of other elements. So, for example, element 5, will be linked to element 6 using *next in the normal linked list way, but then I want to connect element 5 to various other elements, using a separate method.

The method I have chosen is to use a vector of structs (I need a few pieces of extra info in the extra struct for each connection).  Here is the struct that is used in the vector:

```
struct dependency{
    struct node *pDependency;
    short delay;
    dependencyType depType;
};
```

I have had no problem creating the extra connections, but I am having a problem accessing them again afterwards e.g.

```
cout << temp->instrDep.delay << endl;
```

Where temp is the original node and instrDep is the dependency structure, gives me:

**error: 'class std::vector' has no member named 'delay'**

Any ideas????

Comment: The compiler is telling you... vector does not have member field `delay` (your structure does). So you probably want to access one of structs pointed by pointer in your vector, e.g.: `temp->instrDep[0]->delay` (only if you are sure, that there is at least one element in vector).

Comment: Thank you!  I will try it later.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an index. Also as your vector contains pointers, you need to use the `->` operator. To access the nth element in the vector, use

```
cout << temp->instrDep[n]->delay << endl;
```

(assuming that `temp` is a pointer to `node`)

Comment: Of course!! You are a genius.  Thank you very for your help.  I will try it when I get back home.